# Why I cant return configurable products using default RMA

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-2.0.4, rma

I am using magento 2.4 enterprise edition. Products I can generate return requests are of type Simple ,Grouped, Bundled. This is default feature supported by magento. Though I wonder why it is not supported for configurable product? Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging for while I found that, weight in simple product/child product was missing of my configurable product which I added in cart. So it was not showing me shippping option on checkout page.

Hence in first time I placed order withoug shipping method so product was not able to ship. And product which cant be shipped cant be managed for RMA.

Now as I added this weight shipping option is also visible . And once product will be shipped from admin by admin customer can generate RMA for this configurable product too.